# MySQL: fill in the gaps with last known value

Tags: mysql, sql, database, gaps-and-islands

I have a table containing global sales data at different reporting dates like this:

```
    event_id   | date          | sales_on_date
    -----------+---------------+----------
    1          | 2015-01-01    | 1000
    1          | 2015-02-01    | 1500
    1          | 2015-03-01    | 1600
    2          | 2015-01-01    | 200
    2          | 2015-02-01    | 500
    3          | 2015-01-01    | 100
```

And I need to write a SELECT statement to output the sales (or the last known sales) for every date, like this:

```
    event_id   | date          | sales_on_date
    -----------+---------------+----------
    1          | 2015-01-01    | 1000
    1          | 2015-02-01    | 1500
    1          | 2015-03-01    | 1600
    2          | 2015-01-01    | 200
    2          | 2015-02-01    | 500
    2          | 2015-03-01    | 500
    3          | 2015-01-01    | 100
    3          | 2015-02-01    | 100
    3          | 2015-03-01    | 100
```

Currently, I have to make a SQL request to fetch all data from my table, and then use a PHP routine to fill in the gaps, but it seems a 'pure' SQL solution would be much more convenient and elegant.

Any idea how to do this in SQL?

Comment: sql can't fill in gaps either. you'd need a separate table that contains all of the dates you need, which you can join against. in other words, you basically have to replicate in sql what you're doing in php.

Comment: Inserting (and maintaining) redundant data only makes real sense in very specific situations (performance in huge data sets, simplify an otherwise terrible complicated calculation, etc.). Are you sure you can't recreate the expected output on read?

Comment: @Álvaro González  Sorry if my question wasn't clear, I edited it: I don't need to insert data in the table (that would be a bad idea indeed), I just need a SELECT request to output it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit complicated, because the query has two parts.  The first is generating all the rows.  The second is filling them in.  The first is a `CROSS JOIN`.  The second a correlated subquery:

```
select e.event_id, d.date,
       (select t.sales_on_date
        from t
        where t.event_id = e.event_id and t.date <= d.date
        order by t.date desc
        limit 1
       ) as sales_on_date
from (select distinct event_id from t) e cross join
     (select distinct date from t) d
order by e.event_id, d.date;
```